# date_sub is not working

Tags: php, date

As my server is not upgreaded to php 5.3 (it is in PHP Version 5.2.11) date_sub is not working.

here is the code: `$date = date_create(date('Y-m-d'));
                date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('60 days'));
                $date1= date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');`

but its ok in my localhost(which is in 5.3), but not in server(5.2.11).

Can you please tell me how  can i make this date subtraction working on 5.2.11 ?

Answer (score 5):

Like [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) say, use `DateTime::modify()`.

Answer (score 4):

$date1= date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-60 days"));

it works :)

Comment: strtotime is affected by the y2k38 bug on 32-bit platforms. The new DateTime class is not.

Comment: Scouring the web. Depleted from coffee. This answer saved me

Answer (score 1):

for EX $da=2014-04-01

if u want to minus 6 months use this..

```
$date = strtotime($da .' -6 months');
$final=date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

echo $final;

Answer (score 1):

For adding and subracting days

```
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-10 days"));
echo $newdate;
```

sub 10 days

```
$newdate1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+10 days"));
echo $newdate1;
```

add 10 days

For adding and subracting months

```
$newmonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-5 months"));
echo $newmonth;
```

sub 10 months

```
$newmonth1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+5 months"));
echo $newmonth1;
```

add 10 months

Answer (score 0):

As the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-sub.php) says, this function works only for the PHP version >= 5.3.0.
So, you've found right solution yourself